# How can we make call through extension to extension in web using Elastix server?

Tags: php, elastix

I am working elastix server api and I want to use call by web(PHP)like softphone.

For exmaple:
I have two extenstion of elastix server - 1000, 1001 with Domain server(elastix) XXXXXXXXX and secrate key.

Please suggest how can we call from  1000 to 1001 in php?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I do not know how to use PHP for this purpose, but if I understand you well, you would like to make calls from a website. Right? If so, I think you will need a webphone (it is actually a softphone embedded to a website).
I have some knowledge of VoIP development in C#. To implement a webphone in C#, you can use the Silverlight or the Flash technology. After some googling I found [this website](http://www.voip-sip-sdk.com/p_334-webphone-development-voip.html) that says:

> For using web telephony, you and your partner will need webphones to
>   talk through. The webphone is a client-server application. The client
>   part is a program integrated into a website. This client is connected
>   to the webphone server that is usually a console application. The
>   server forwards the call to another party, which can be another
>   webphone, a softphone, a regular IP phone or even a call center. Using
>   webphones is a very convenient way of communicating with your
>   customers, as they can call you directly from your webpage.

The mentioned page provides more details about Silverlight and Flash and it also offers some C# code examples.

I hope it helped you to get started.